# Click on the google map to open a link in a new window

Tags: javascript, jquery

I used the code from a website as shown below to let me show a google map in my page.
You can see it in action here http://www.pcpro.co.uk/blogs/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/google-maps-simple-example.html

My question is how can i change the code to when a user clicks on the map to open a link in a new window?

Thank you

```
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Define the latitude and longitude positions
        var latitude = parseFloat("38.1447817");
        var longitude = parseFloat("23.848843");
        var latlngPos = new google.maps.LatLng(latitude, longitude);
        // Set up options for the Google map
        var myOptions = {
            zoom: 15,
            center: latlngPos,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        };
        // Define the map
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), myOptions);
        // Add the marker
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlngPos,
            map: map,
            title: "Auto Marin"
        });
    });
</script>


<div id="map" style="width:230px;height:140px;"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add an [event listener.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/events)

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(){
     window.open(*LINK*)
});
```